# How to calculate a digest of pdf document

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I need to implement signing a pdf document in two steps. In the first step I need to calculate a pdf digest and in the second step, I need to sign this document.

I have a problem with step 1 (calculating pdf digest). If I run the digest calculation several times with identical data, I have different digests.
When I checked the document that has been passed to the digest calculation method, I found the Modification date was different in these calls.[image: Modification date is different]
But If I do it with the PdfBox library, I always get correct results, and the Modification Date doesn’t change
**How can I calculate the pdf digest and don’t update the modified date?**
My code looks like the following:

```
public class MyDigestCalculator extends ExternalBlankSignatureContainer {
     public byte[] pdfDigest;
    
    public MyDigestCalculator(PdfName filter, PdfName subFilter) {
        super(filter, subFilter);
    }

     @Override
    public byte[] sign(InputStream is) throws GeneralSecurityException {
           try {
         final byte[] bytes = is.readAllBytes();
             final String pdf = new String(bytes);
       
          BouncyCastleDigest digestService = new BouncyCastleDigest();
          pdfDigest = DigestAlgorithms.digest(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), “SHA-256”);
          return new byte[0];
       } catch (IOException e) {
          throw new GeneralSecurityException("Can't get digest from file hash", e);
       }
    }
}

public class DocumentSigner {
    public String calculatePdfDigest(byte[] pdfBytes, SignatureProperties signature, boolean lockFields, Calendar signDate) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        final PdfDocument pdfDocument = createPdfDocument(pdfBytes);
       PdfAcroForm acroForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDocument, false);
       acroForm.setSignatureFlags(PdfAcroForm.SIGNATURE_EXIST);
               
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfBytes));
     PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, baos, new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());

    signer.setSignDate(signDate);
    MyDigestCalculator calcDigest = new MyDigestCalculator(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);

    signer.signExternalContainer(calcDigest, 8120);
    pdfBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String digest = (digestHash != null ? new BigInteger(1, calcDigest.pdfDigest).toString(16) : null);
    return digest;
}

}
```

Comment: Have you checked whether the changed modification date in the xmp metadata is the only difference? At least the ID could also differ...

Comment: That being said, the iText signing API is designed so that for this use case you'd actually _keep_ the output of the first `signExternalContainer` and later inject the CMS signature container created for your hash using `PdfSigner.signDeferred`.

Comment: @mkl I have checked it. The only modification date was changed. I can't understand why it happened because I didn't modify the pdf. I get the original pdf and run my code two times and I always get different pdf digests for the same document. The ```signDate``` the same in the both cases

Comment: @mkl The pdf digest should be the same if I calculate it for the one pdf with the same parameters. Am I right?

Comment: Your code does not merely calculate a digest, it first prepares the PDF for signing. This is a modification. As iText automatically updates the modification time, therefore, you get different results and hashes in multiple runs for the same PDF.

Comment: @mkl How can I do the workflow looks like the following: 1. I Get a pdf file and fill in all fields. 2. I need to calculate the digest and send it to the server for getting the certificates and ocsps data. 3. I should sign this pdf file. When I add certificates to the pdf and try to sign it the modification date is changed and the digest already different. Can you give me advice how can I realize this workflow? What do I do wrong?

Comment: See my second comment. _The iText signing API is designed so that for this use case you'd actually keep the output of the first `signExternalContainer` call and later inject the CMS signature container created for your hash using `PdfSigner.signDeferred`._